# ¿Porque no ejecuta la orden qué le doy?

Tags: python

```
    import os

# Agregar artículos
def agregar_articulo():

    archivo_lista = open("lista.txt", "a")

    articulo = input("Ingrese un artículo a la lista: ")

    archivo_lista.write("{}\n".format(articulo))

    archivo_lista.close()

# Ver los artículos
def ver_articulos():

    mostrar_archivo = open("lista.txt", "r")

    print(mostrar_archivo)

    mostrar_archivo.close()

# Borra el archivo que contiene la lista de compras
def borrar_lista():

    os.remove("lista.txt")



def compra_app():
    # UI
    print("#######Bienvenido a COMPRAPP###########")

    eleccion = print(input("Qué desea hacer: \n 1- Agregar un artículo \n 2- Ver los articulos agregados"
                     "\n 3- Borrar la lista \n 4- Salir "))

    while eleccion != 4:

        if eleccion == 1:

            agregar_articulo()

        elif eleccion == 2:

            ver_articulos()

        elif eleccion == 3:

            borrar_lista()
    # Salir
    print("#######Gracias y hasta la proxima!######")


compra_app()
```

Ademas no muestra ningún error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos errores principalmente, el primero está en la línea:

```
eleccion = print(input("Qué desea hacer: ..."))
```

**`eleccion` es el retorno de `print` y `print` retorna siempre `None`**. No necesitas usar `print` para nada en esta línea, `input` ya imprime la cadena que se le pasa como argumento cuando pide la entrada del usuario. Como `eleccion` es `None` la condición del `while` siempre es cierta (`None != 4`), por lo que entra en el ciclo, pero como `eleccion` tampoco es `1`, `2` o `3` no entra en ninguna de las condiciones. Al no modificar el valor de `eleccion` dentro del propio ciclo `while` entras en un ciclo infinito.

Para tu código la línea debería ser:

```
eleccion = int(input("Qué desea hacer: ..."))
```

El otro error es que el `input` debes pedirlo **dentro del `while`** como ya se ha comentado. Tampoco está de más que valides la entrada por si el usuario no ingresa una opción válida, por ejemplo:

```
def compra_app():
    # UI
    print("#######Bienvenido a COMPRAPP###########")

    while True:
        eleccion = input("Qué desea hacer:\n"
                         " 1- Agregar un artículo\n"
                         " 2- Ver los articulos agregados\n"
                         " 3- Borrar la lista\n"
                         " 4- Salir\n"
                         ">> ")

        if eleccion == '1':
            agregar_articulo()

        elif eleccion == '2':
            ver_articulos()

        elif eleccion == '3':
            borrar_lista()

        elif eleccion == '4':
            break

        else:
            print("Opción no válida. Vuelva a intentarlo.\n")

    # Salir
    print("#######Gracias y hasta la proxima!######")
```